# Can't unlock screen

Tags: 16.04, lock-screen

Several days ago I faced a problem: after locking screen with Alt+Ctrl+L the screen turns off as expected, but when I try to wake it (move mouse, press any button) and type password the screen turns on but I only see black screen and cursor on it. I have to reboot computer and login again.

I tried to call Alt+Ctrl+F7 and so on, but nothing helps.

Some days ago I've changed `vm.swappiness` parameter with command `sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10`. Maybe it cause the problem.
I use `Linux 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP`
Thanks.

UPD:
Another way to awake it is to run `systemctl restart lightdm`

UPD:
I did the fresh install and it worked until I'd updated packages. One of them cause the problem. How can I detect which of them?

UPD: All packages have been updated (http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25177450/), which of them can cause the problem?

UPD: I've booted with the previous version of the kernel (4.8.0.36) and all works fine. What should I do now? Should I write bugreport or something else?

UPD:

Link to bug on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1706713

Comment: Why not take it (swappiness) back to default value and see if it was the cause!

Comment: I did it back and it does not help

Comment: Did you restart the system and then tried?

Comment: Much times and after locking I get the same problem

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem has just started occurring in the last two days or so.

Comment: @LonnieBest, I've created issue on launchpad. Please, press "this bug affect me" https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1706713

Comment: Ok, I marked mine as a duplicate: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1706764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as booting to previous version of the kernel helped me I suppose it's a bug.